# How to read Microsoft Logger extension high memory usage from dump

Tags: memory, asp.net-core, memory-leaks, .net-core, autofac

My .NET Core 2 API running on App Service has an ever growing memory-usage. Going up to the point the app service crashes and we need to restart it. Last time I made a memory dump in Kudu and opened it in VS2017.

I'm a rookie in analyzing this file, but sorting on the Inclusive Size, almost all logging objects claim a lot of RAM. See attached print-screen:

[image: High memory usage]

I think that somehow these resources are not disposed. A sample of my Autofac-container configuration is below:

```
    var assemblies = new Assembly[]
    {
        Assembly.Load("....")

    };

    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
        .Where(t => !t.Name.EndsWith("CachedRepository") && !t.Name.EndsWith("DbCachedRepository"))
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .InstancePerBackgroundJob() // Dispose after Hangfire job
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope(); // Dispose after http request
```

How can I control the disposal of the Logger objects?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/821

Comment: Thank you @davidfowl. This helped a lot stabalizing the app on Azure. I just disabled blob log in the diagnostics.

Comment: @JonHendrix Do you still have the dump? I'm trying to fix the issue with azure logger it would help to have the dump.

Comment: @PavelKrymets I'm so sorry, we don't have the dump anymore. I checked KUDU but I've deleted it there too. FYI: I think because I've set the min-log-level to information, a sick load of messages was flushed to the Azure Logger. Reflecting, I think it is not strange a logging service will crash on that :).

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by reading the link provided by David Fowl. It's a github issue with a kown Azure Logging problem. See https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/821.

After disabling the blob logger, everything was solved.